# Dynamically set agrument type java

Tags: java, generics, rx-java

I have a method which creates simple `Observer` for JavaRX that looks like

```
protected Observer observer;

protected <T> void createObserver(Class<T> type) {
    observer = new Observer() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object value) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
        }
    };
}
```

How can I set current **type** in `onNext` method? I mean I want to have something like this

```
    @Override
    public void onNext(type value) {
    }
```

But this doesn`t work.

Comment: Do you mean that you know the possible types of `value` and you want to do some type specific operation or do you simply want it to be the type denoted by the type variable `T`.

Comment: @glee8e, I set type of value as argument in createObserver method. So I want to have object of class I set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
protected <T> void createObserver(Class<T> type) {
    observer = new Observer<T>() { // <-- It's possible to assign types with  arbitrary type arguments to a raw type.
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(T value) { // <-- Now it's legal
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
        }
    };
}
```

However, there won't be much difference because you are completeky unaware of what `T` may be, and it's effectively just `java.lang.Object`, unless you know what `value` you may receive.

Comment: Thats answer, but I got that I cant do thing I wanted =( cuz java doesnt let. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The `observer` field would have to be of type `Observer<?>` which makes it useless.